# How create this design with only CSS3 and HTML5 and without JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

### How create this design  with only CSS3 and HTML5 and without JavaScript ?

**Header** (contains image) :

- height : dynamic (depends on image width)
- position : fixed

---

**content** (contains text) :

- height : dynamic (height of layout - (header+footer))
- Scroll when text exceeds the height of content

---

**Footer** :

- height : fixed
- position : fixed

Comment: Try using bootsrap framework

Comment: I'm pretty sure bootstrap uses js, though.

Comment: If you want to do some responsive design in CSS, I suggest you look at media queries : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: What approaches and methods have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I guess your goal ist to keep the footer on the bottom. Take a look at this basic tutorial:
http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

By the way: Everything concerning layouting is done with html and css. Javascript just alters html/css and doesn't changes the layout itself.

Comment: Good call re: Javascript.